# R: use one list to modify another list efficiently

Tags: r, list, data-manipulation

I am trying to modify one list based information contained in another list.  The essence of the problem is that one list `list1` contains data frames--two columns each, column 1 (`time`) = time instants, column 2 (`score`) is filled with 0s--and the other list `list2` contains data frames--two columns containing paired time instances (e.g. 0.12 and 0.125 or 1.54 and 1.57), or the start and end points of a time window.  Each data frame in `list1` has a corresponding (i.e. same name) data frame in `list2`

The goal is to figure out which time instants (i.e. from the `time` column) from each data frame in `list1` do fall in between any of the time windows contained in the associated data frame in `list2` by modifying the 'score' column from data frames in `list1` (the one with all zeros) if its associated time instant is between at least one of the paired times from the corresponding (i.e. same name) data frame from `list2`.  The end result is essentially `list1` with 0s in the `score` column distinguishing time instants that do not fall in any window from the time instants that do.

Here is some example data:

```
set.seed(1)
list1 <- split(d<-replicate(10,1:100+rnorm(100,0,0.1)), 
         ceiling(seq_along(d)/100))
list1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) data.frame(cbind(time = x, score = 0)))
names(list1) <- letters[1:10]

list2 <- replicate(10, sample(1:100, sample(1:20), replace=FALSE)) 
list2 <- lapply(list2, function(x) 
         data.frame(cbind(x, x + sample(runif(100,min=0.1,max=3),length(x)))))
names(list2) <- letters[1:10]
```

I was able to cobble together a solution or two that work for small examples, but when I try it on my much larger list (i.e. several million time instants in the real `list1`), I run into memory errors.

First, I made a function to do what I want given two appropriate data frames

```
testfxn1 <-function(df1, df2)
  {
    df1<-lapply(1:dim(df2)[1], function(x)
    {
    df1[which(df1[1] > df2[x,1] & df1[1] < df2[x,2]), 2] <- 1
    return(df1)
    })
    return(cbind(df1[[1]][1], 
           score = rowSums(do.call(cbind,lapply(df1,'[[',2)))))
  }
```

Then, I use `sapply` to apply the function to the whole list:

```
sapply(names(list1), simplify=FALSE, function(x) return(testfxn1(list1[[x]], list2[[x]])))
```

It does what I want (i.e. leaves 0s where the data are not between a relevant time window), but in my real data there are many data frames with 250,000 - 750,000 time instants in `list1` and I am unable to allocate enough memory to complete the task.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this more efficiently?  Surely, the first `lapply` call in my `testfxn1` must be a big part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will be faster.

```
res <- setNames(lapply(names(list1), function(x) {
         x1 <- list2[[x]]
         x2 <- list1[[x]][, 1]
         x3 <- t(replicate(length(x2), x1[, 1]))
         x4 <- t(replicate(length(x2), x1[, 2]))
            data.frame(time = x2, score = rowSums(x2 > x3 & x2 < x4))
      }), names(list1))

 s1 <- sapply(names(list1), simplify=FALSE, function(x) return(testfxn1(list1[[x]], list2[[x]])))     

 identical(res, s1)
  #[1] TRUE
```

Another way would be:

```
 library(data.table)
 x1 <- rbindlist(list1)
 x2 <- rbindlist(list2)

 #slower
 s3 <- Vectorize(function(x) x1[, time] > x)(x2[, x]) & Vectorize(function(y) x1[, 
time] < y)(x2[, V2])
 indx <- rep(names(list2), sapply(list2, dim)[1, ])
 indx2 <- seq(1, nrow(x1), by = 100)
 lst1 <- split(seq_len(ncol(s3)), indx)
 res1 <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(indx2), function(i) data.frame(time = list1[[i]][, 
1], score = rowSums(s3[indx2[i]:(indx2[i] + 99), lst1[[i]]]))), names(list1))

 identical(res,res1)
 #[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little faster, if I'm understanding the problem correctly. You can at least remove one set of loops through vectorization.

```
windows = rbind(list2[[1]], list2[[2]])
# for each time, look at all windows and see if the time t falls outsize every single window:
list1[[1]]$score = sapply(list1[[1]]$time, FUN=function(t){
    all(t > windows[,1] | t < windows[,2])
}) 
# same thing for the second dataframe in list1
# TRUE = in a window, FALSE = not in a window. Use as.numeric() to coerce to 0's and 1's.
```

Answer (score 1):

@HillarySanders answer gave me an idea.

For my purposes, this answer yields the same relevant information as `testfxn1`, though there is a post processing step necessary here to join the output here with the original `list1` time instant data.

```
testfxn2 <- function(df1, df2)
  {
  sapply(df1$time, function(g)
    {
    any(g > df2[,1] & g < df2[,2])
    })
  }
```

Then `sapply` it:

```
sapply(names(list1), simplify=FALSE, function(x) testfxn2(list1[[x]], list2[[x]]))
```

Comment: Nice! Note that you can omit the `return` statement, and in general it's not recommended to use it in R.

Answer (score 1):

There may be better approaches, yet, but for sure a significant part of the memory crunch is with the many copies of `df1` (each with a few ones rather than zeros for the `score` value, where appropriate).   An alternative approach is to use a single copy of `df1` where we increment the corresponding entry whenever the time matches.  Furthermore this approach saves the need of recreating df1 with sums, at the end.
In other words:

```
# alternative to original tesetfxn1() function
#   The idea is to increment the value in the qualifying rows in-situ rather
#   than producing as many copies of df1 as there are rows in df2 and having to
#   sum these up at the end.
testfxn1 <-function(df1, df2)
{
    for (x in 1:nrow(df2))  # I find this more explicit that 1:dim(df2)[1]
    {
        # Get "list" of qualifying rows
        selectRows <- which(df1[1] > df2[x,1] & df1[1] < df2[x,2])
        # Increment the corresponding row's score value
        if (length(selectRows) > 0) {
          df1[selectRows, 2] <- df1[selectRows, 2] + 1
          # or more explicitly...
          # df1[selectRows, ]$score <- df1[selectRows, ]$score + 1
        }
    }

    df1
}
```